# More $1$s than $0$s in recursively defined set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let $S$ be the set of strings defined recursively by:

Basis Step: $1 \in S$

Recursive Step: If $s \in S$, then $01s \in S$, $10s \in S$, $0s1 \in S$, $1s0 \in S$, $s10 \in S$, $s01 \in S$, $s1 \in S$ and $1s \in S$.

1. Prove that if $s \in S$ then "$1$" occurs in $s$ more times than "$0$".
2. Is $10011 \in S$ ?  If so, show how to construct $10011$ from the definition?  If not, why not?

I simply have no clue where to start with this.  Please explain step by step how you do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are not fully confident applying induction yet, so I have included more details than normally required for this kind of problem.

1.
Induction hypothesis: Assume that for some number of recursive steps, $n$, any string $s$ produced from applying $n$ rules to $1 \in S$ contains more 1's than 0's.

Inductive step: We wish to show that any string produced from applying $n+1$ rules to $1 \in S$ contains more 1's than 0's. By the induction hypothesis, we know that after $n$ of those steps, the result $s$ has more 1's than 0's. Applying another rule to $s$ will make $n+1$ steps and create one of $\{01s, 10s, 0s1, 1s0, s10, s01, s1, 1s\}$. We see that in all cases, the number of 1's increase by 1, while the number of 0's increase by at most 1, so since $s$ had more 1's than 0's, after applying another rule that is still the case, which is what we wished to show.

Base case: Any string produced after applying $0$ rules to $1 \in S$ is simply $1$ which has more 1's than 0's.

Conclusion: When $n=0$, the induction hypothesis is true. We have shown that if the induction hypothesis is true for $n$, then it is true for $n+1$ as well. So it is true for $0, 1, 2, \dots$. But the strings produced after $0, 1, 2, \dots$ applications of rules are exactly the elements of $S$, so for any $s \in S$ we can find a value of $n$ for which the induction hypothesis is true and thus $s$ has more 1's than 0's.

2. Yes. $1 \in S \implies 01(1) \in S \implies 10(011) \in S$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can prove there are more 1's than 0's by induction on the number of recursive steps, starting with the string $1$ which has no recursive steps. All you need is that each recursive step weakly increases the difference between the number of 1 minus the number of 0.

Comment: but isn't induction just where you know n is true for something and you try and prove n+1?  Wouldn't, n being 1, n + 1 be 2?  How would this work then?

Comment: Here $n$ is the number of recursive rules you apply before you decide you are done generating your string in $S$.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would start this?  and why does 1 have no recursive steps?

Comment: Would the way to prove this just be to plugin certain numbers for s?  because I know plugging in 1 for s gives you 011, 101, 011, 110, 110, 101, 11, and 11, which has more 1s than 0s, but plugging in 0 gives more 0s than 1s, so how is this true?

Comment: Ok- I think I kind of understand.  Based on what I think I'm supposed to do, because I know 1 ∈ S, then all of the numbers resulting from replacing the s in the recursive step with 1, are also ∈ S.  Each of those resulting numbers have more 1s than 0s in them, but how many times would I have to do this to prove it?  Like would I have to do the recursive steps again on the numbers created by replacing s with 1?  Because I feel like that would never end.